# Which app they used here?

Tags: arranging

If you listen to the intro it is processed/arranged with "people whispering" voices

How can we achieve such effect ? 
do you know an app or a way to achieve it ?
And how can you describe the atmosphere that the listeners achieve by applying this effect ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just sampling. All you need is a mic and something that records. The rest is effects processing such as reverb.

Any standard DAW will provide the tools you need.